# How to extract specific parts of a URL and replace with different data

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I have a specific type url and i need to identify some parts of it and replace with some data, url would be `www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},param2={{^user id^}}`,....

What i need to do is, identify `{{^User Name^}}` and `{{^user id^}}` and replace with my values,

Anybody have an idea to do this with flex?

A friend of mine told me to use RegExp for this, but I'm clueless about how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, no expert on RegExp tho.

```
var s:String = "www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},param2={{^user id^}}";
var userPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param1=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9 ])*(\^}})/;
var userIdPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param2=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9 ])*(\^}})/;
s = s.replace(userPattern,'username');
s = s.replace(userIdPattern,'user_id');
```

If you want to replace only the string inside {{}} maby this would work:

```
var s:String = "www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},param2={{^user id^}}";
var userPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param1={{)\^([A-Za-z0-9 ])*\^(?=}})/;
var userIdPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param2={{)\^([A-Za-z0-9 ])*\^(?=}})/;
s = s.replace(userPattern,'username');
s = s.replace(userIdPattern,'user_id');
```

To remove multiple {{}} for exampe www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},{{^,e,^}},param2={{^user id^}} between paramX try this:

```
var s:String = "www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},{{^,e,^}},param2={{^user id^}}";
var userPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param1={{)\^([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(?=}})/;
var userIdPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param2={{)\^([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(?=}})/;
s = s.replace(userPattern,'username');
s = s.replace(userIdPattern,'user_id');
```

Output should be www.something.com@param1={{username}},param2={{user_id}}.

Another example:

```
var s:String = "www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},{{^,e,^}},param2={{^user id^}}";
var userPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param1=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(})/;
var userIdPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param2=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(})/;
s = s.replace(userPattern,'username');
s = s.replace(userIdPattern,'user_id');
```

Output should be www.something.com@param1=username,param2=user_id.

Comment: eldamar, Thanks a lot your first solution helps to solve the problem for some extent.However, i got a small problem when using above regEx, when i use it it returns the {{^User Name^}} tag with additional characters, something like this {{^Field Name^}},{{^,e,^}}. if i can get rid of this additional tags, i can easily manage to resolve my problem. Same thing happens to other regEx as well. (userIdPattern).

Comment: Not sure i understand but you need to add all the expected characters inside {{}} by adding them to the [A-Za-z0-9 ] part of the RegEx, ex: [A-Za-z0-9,.-@# ]

Comment: What i meant by additional tags is {{^,e,^}} part. When i run above script "s.match(userpattern)" it returns this -{{^Field Name^}},{{^,e,^}}. i am looking a way to get rid of  {{^,e,^}} part from above return value. what i need only {{^Field Name^}} part. Thanks

Comment: eldmar, sorry for troubling u again, Could you please able to provide me the relavant java reg exp for the same? when i try to compile above pattern in java it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient or nice solution but it will get the work done. 
Simply update the replace() function to manage different types of parameters.

```
public static const START_TAG:String = "{{^";
public static const END_TAG:String = "^}}";

public function replace():void {
    var url:String = "param1={{^User Name^}},param2={{^user id^}}";

    while ( getTagStartIndex(url) >= 0 ) {
      var currentTag:String = getTagContent(url);
      var value:String = "";
      if ( currentTag == "User Name" ) {
        value = "myName";
      } else if ( currentTag == "user id" ) {
        value = "myID";
      } else {
        value = "undefinedtag";
      }
      url = replaceTagWithValue(currentTag,value, url);
     }

    }

protected function getTagStartIndex(str:String):int {
    return str.indexOf(START_TAG);
}

protected function getTagEndIndex(str:String):int {
    return str.indexOf(END_TAG, getTagStartIndex(str+1));
}

protected function getTagContent(str:String):String {
    return str.substring(getTagStartIndex(str)+START_TAG.length, getTagEndIndex(str));
}

protected function replaceTagWithValue(tag:String, tagValue:String, str:String):String {
    return str.replace(START_TAG+tag+END_TAG,tagValue);
}
```

Comment: Nope, I need to replace whole {{^User Name^}} part with my value and not everytime i get User name in it, it can be different value, but {{^__ __^}} part wont be changed. What i want is to identify {{}} part and get the value in it, in this case "user Name" and replace whole thing with my value.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand clearly what you want, but I have updated my answer. You can of course call replace more than one time to change the values of more than one parameter.

Comment: Davz,Thanks for your thoughts, but problem here is i will not know the exact value inside the brackets, it can be a different value, say one time it can be User Name but next time it can be a different value Eg> "Address". So i cant use replace function witout knowing what is inside, What i want is, extract the value in brackets and get the value to be replaced from another table using orginal parameter value,and replace the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\{\{\^.*\^\}\}
```

Useful tool for this: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/