# Flex RegExp to Java RegExp

Tags: java, regex, apache-flex

Recently i was looking for help to extract some pattern of a URL using RegExp in flex, Few guys kindly helped me to get it done. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358756/how-to-extract-specific-parts-of-a-url-and-replace-with-different-data) I need to do it again in java layer, i tried to applied the same regExp pattern in java, but it gives me an error.

```
var s:String = "www.something.com@param1={{^User Name^}},{{^,e,^}},param2={{^user id^}}";
var userPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param1=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(})/;
var userIdPattern:RegExp = /(?<=param2=)({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9\^}}{{, ])*(})/;
s = s.replace(userPattern,'username');
s = s.replace(userIdPattern,'user_id');
```

This gives the www.something.com@param1=username,param2=user_id.

Can somebody help me out to do this in java layer, relavent regular expression is enough.

This is what i tried in java,

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/@param1={{^Case Name^}},param2={{^Case Id^}}";
String urlPattern = "/({{\\^)([A-Za-z0-9_\\^}}{{, ])*(})/";
Pattern paramPattern = Pattern.compile(urlPattern);     
Matcher matcher = paramPattern.matcher(url);       
System.out.println("Matches - "+matcher.matches());
System.out.println("Find - "+matcher.find());
```

It gives this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
>   /({{\^)([A-Za-z0-9_\^}}{{, ])*(})/

Comment: How are you creating this in Java and what is the error?

Comment: Sly_cardinal, thx, question is updated.

Comment: Note: you should not include the slashes `/` within your `urlPattern`. They are not necessary and are treated as simple characters.

Comment: Howard, thx, but it doesnt make any different even if i removed them.It shows error at first "(" character.

Answer (score 2):

`{` is a meta character in Java regexes, for bounded repetition, e.g. `a{1,2}` matches at least 1, at most 2 'a's. As you are not using it for repetition, you ought to escape each `{` with `\\`.

Comment: Hi Antti, thx, But could you please be more specify? What should i do with the current code?

Comment: @bluelabel Escaping means putting backslashes before the chars. Try `"(\\{\\{\\^)([A-Za-z0-9_\\^\\}\\}\\{\\{, ])*(\\})"`.

Comment: Thx, Howard, it helped a lot.

Comment: Sly-cardinal, It helped me to sort out the issues,