# Java regex error Illegal repetition

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flex RegExp to Java RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963263/flex-regexp-to-java-regexp)

I don't know why is it not working.. I'm using java..

```
...
String patternString = "([^{}]*{[^{}]+}[^{}])*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
...
```

The error that i receive is:

```
Illegal repetition near index 4
([^{}]*{[^{}]+}[^{}]*)
```

Comment: `{`, `}` are metacharacters, escape them with "\\".

Comment: `Illegal repetition near index 6` on my system ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the literal braces unless they're inside a character class:

```
String patternString = "([^{}]*\\{[^{}]+\\}[^{}])*";
```

Most other regex flavors can recognize when braces are not being used as a repetition operator (as in `[0-9]{1,3}`) and therefore will parse the regex correctly. But Java is insistent on having these braces escaped.